# Paypal gateway has rejected request. (#11601) Billing address request is not enabled for merchant

Tags: paypal

It is the PayPal account settings. https://share.getcloudapp.com/qGuJz7gG

I've tried to enable that, but PayPal stopped working with the following response.h https://share.getcloudapp.com/lluowEyn.

According to the description in the config, this setting has to be enabled in the merchant account and it can be done via the request to PayPal support.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, PayPal's technical support would not enable any such account feature, and people that tell you that PayPal's technical support would (including in your screenshot) are simply wrong.. PayPal's technical support never enables account features, they only advise on errors/bugs and integration/development questions.

Only the regular business support (https://www.paypal.com/smarthelp/contact-us or a PayPal account manager (if you have one) could enable such an account feature.

However, they simply will not do it. This feature is highly restricted; billing information is kept private to buyers' accounts by design.

So, in the configuration settings for your PayPal payment method, ensure "Require Customer's Billing Address" remains set to **No**.